# Are carnival-style games still available in Taiwanese night markets?

Tags: culture, taiwan, entertainment

In [Show them the door: Taiwan's netizens ashamed of loutish tourists](http://www.wantchinatimes.com/news-subclass-cnt.aspx?id=20140717000128&cid=1303), there's mention of a Taiwanese night market game:

> The doors, with their paper panels punched through, resembled a
>   popular night market game in which players punch out panels on a grid
>   of small boxes to win a prize behind.

**Are carnival-style games still available in Taiwanese night markets?** I'm especially interested in anything more "traditional" or specific to Taiwan, such as the game described.

I went to the Shilin night market (described as the most "touristy" of them), and I don't think I saw carnival-style games.

Comment: I still couldn't find specific enough information for an answer, but here's a link with pictures of a couple of those [games](http://www.aspirantsg.com/carnival-of-food-games-at-wusheng-night-market-tainan/). You have to scroll down past all those food pictures to get to the games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They definitely still exist - they're more common in the southern part of Taiwan, but if you're looking in Taipei, the one near Fu Jen University had quite a bunch last time I went. https://guidetotaipei.com/visit/fu-jen-university-fu-da-garden-night-market-%E8%BC%94%E5%A4%A7%E8%8A%B1%E5%9C%92%E5%A4%9C%E5%B8%82

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, and here are my sources:

[Night Markets in Taiwan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_markets_in_Taiwan) on Wikipedia:

> Carnival-style games are typically available to play for the price of
>   a few coins. The night market in Tamsui is especially well known for
>   featuring traditional carnival games such as balloon shooting, net
>   fish, shooting marbles, and an assortment of mini games that could
>   only have otherwise been seen many years ago.

Now, that may have been edited, because almost word for word on [FormosaTravel](http://www.formosatravel.net/the-basics/19-the-basics/6-taiwans-night-market.html) they state the same, but about a different market. Presumably it's true for both.

> In addition, carnival-style games are typically available to play for
>   the price of a few coins. The night market in Dan-shui especially
>   features some traditional carnival games. Such as balloon shooting,
>   net fish, shooting marbles and many mini games.

Finally, an article on AspirantSG, entitled [Carnival Of Food & Games At Wusheng Night Market 武聖夜市 Tainan](http://www.aspirantsg.com/carnival-of-food-games-at-wusheng-night-market-tainan/) features Wusheng Night Market, and has plenty of photos as evidence of games.

Comment: "Tamsui" and "Dan-shui" are different romanisations of the same location. "Tamsui District (Chinese: 淡水區, formerly Tamshui Township), also Danshui" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamsui_District)

Comment: AH, that explains that then - double confirmation :D